# Why do I get the error given by Paypal, Opencart, Journal 3

Tags: paypal, opencart, opencart-module

I have such an error with the Paypal payment system, installed at Opencart,popup is opened and an error appears in the console
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vfu6m.png)
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSatg.png)

I searched everywhere, I can't find a way out of the situation, I use Thema Journal 3

Comment: Have you tried disable Journal? Do you receive the same error? If no this error can be related with journal. Officially journal is not supported by OpenCart.

Comment: I tried to disconnect it, it still doesn't want to start, probably lost many customers because of this